# How to use this,parent concept of jquery in Angular?

Tags: jquery, html, angular

I am beginner in angular2 and I have below code in jquery and html. 
I have to implement this in angular2. what is the best way to do this.
One of my friend suggest me to do with element ref. But I don't have any idea 
please suggest me the best way with example and explanation.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.btn').click(function(){
                    $(this).parent().css("background-color","yellow");
                })
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div style="background-color:black; width:200px; height:50px; margin:10px;">
            <input class="btn" type="button" value="change color" style="" />
        </div>
        <div style="background-color:cyan; width:200px; height:50px; margin:10px;">
            <input class="btn" type="button" value="change color" style="" />
        </div>
        <div style="background-color:green; width:200px; height:50px;  margin:10px;">
            <input class="btn" type="button" value="change color" style="" />
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Start off learning the concepts of Angular. Consider to use Angular CLI to have an easy start. https://angular.io/tutorial

Comment: Hello there. Firstly understand what exactly angular2 is and how it works. Visit https://angular.io link to get more information about angular and then try this by yourself.

Comment: This question is not relate to angular cli @MeMeMax

Comment: So...whats the problem? It is just a suggestion to have an easy start.

Comment: @amitsingh what Mememax told is correct. seems to be you are not completely aware of the difference between jquery based and angular based development. please check the angular documentation

Answer (score 1):

There are several way to archive this in angular2, i'm using here intilization in the constructor or `ngOnInit` hook of angular like this

```
ngOnInit() {
    $('.btn').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().css("background-color","yellow");
    })
}
```

In html

```
<div style="background-color:black; width:200px; height:50px; margin:10px;">
    <input id='abc' class="btn" type="button" value="change color" style="" />
</div>
<div style="background-color:cyan; width:200px; height:50px; margin:10px;">
    <input id='abc' class="btn" type="button" value="change color" style="" />
</div>
<div style="background-color:green; width:200px; height:50px;  margin:10px;">
    <input id='abc' class="btn" type="button" value="change color" style="" />
</div>
```

PS: Basically you can add code in constructor which you want to use on document load like you did in `document.ready...`

Answer (score 0):

Your friends suggestion is a good solution for your problem:

To use ElementRef you should create a (attribute) directive (https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives)

You need ElementRef to get the current Element in the DOM where the Directive is implemented.

I recommend you to read about those and play through the tutorial on the Angular page

Here is an example:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
declare const $: any; // Reverse for jQuery. Don't forget to include jQuery in your project!

  @Directive({
    selector: '[appButton]'
  })

  export class ButtonDirective implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    $(this.el.nativeElement).click(function(){
      $(this).parent().css({
        'background-color': 'yellow'
      });
    });
  }
}
```

To finally use this directive implement it like this:

```
<div style="background-color:black; width:200px; height:50px; margin:10px;">
  <input appButton class="btn" type="button" value="change color" style="" />
</div>
<div style="background-color:cyan; width:200px; height:50px; margin:10px;">
  <input appButton class="btn" type="button" value="change color" style="" />
</div>
<div style="background-color:green; width:200px; height:50px; margin:10px;">
  <input appButton class="btn" type="button" value="change color" style="" />
</div>
```